# Ubuntu 12.04, sony vaio T11, no hardware wifi button, networkmanager "enable wireless" unavailable

Tags: wireless, networking, hardware, vaio, sony

My Sony Vaio T11 does not have a hardware button to enable/disable wifi. When I disable wifi in NetworkManager and reboot "enable wireless" is not available (grayed out) in Networkmanager.

```
$>rfkill list wifi
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
1: sony-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
```

Different to similar problems of this kind "rfkill unblock all" does not help.
However I can boot into windows, start the wifi there and when I reboot to linux wifi is working again.

Comment: Please post output of `lspci -vvv` & `sudo lshw -class network`

Answer (score 3):

Using the NetworkManager command line tool to enable wifi solved my problem:

```
nmcli nm wifi on
```

Seems like the NetworkManager believed that the hardware switch was turned off and dimmed the "enable wireless" due to that "wrong" information. However forcing to enable wireless with the command line tool worked.

Comment: I have spent many hours looking for this, Thank you so much.